# AngularJS how to hook into the head tag from the template of the ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I'm used to using Laravel's Blade template engine, but now that I'm learning to use AngularJS on the front-end, I have given up blade.

I am trying to include some page specific script tags that I don't want to include on my main `<ng-view></ng-view>` page

For example, my main page would look something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        // want to be able to inject stuff here from the ng-view's template
    </head>
    <body>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    <body>
</html>
```

and normally with laravel I can include a `@yield` in the head tag so that later in my template I can just do `@section` to gain access to the head tag. Is there something similar that I can do with Angular?

Comment: I believe you will have to create a separate controller inside the head tag.  The controller in the ng-view can then share data with the head controller using the rootScope or a service for example.

Comment: How would I go about creating a controller in the head tag?

Comment: why do you want to modify your header from a controller what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to be able to inject script or css tags into my head tag from a template view

Comment: Just add an ng-controller="HeaderController" attribute to the head tag.  Then define the controller in your angular app.  You should the be able to output script and link tags using ng-repeat for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, try

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script ng-repeat="script in headScripts" ng-src="script"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ng-view>
            <div ng-click="addHeadScript('/scripts/new.js');"></div>
        </ng-view>
    <body>
</html>

var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.run('$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.headScripts = [];
    $rootScope.addHeadScript = function(src){
        $rootScope.headScripts.push(src);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this solution, I got it to work within my controller using the `rootScope` instead of inside `app.run`, and one minor tweak to make this solution work is that inside of `ng-src` the script needs to be wrapped inside of interpolation tags, `{{ script }}`